# Laravel 5: Sending email with attached .pdf file generated from dynamic page

Tags: laravel, email, pdf, attachment

I have a job website. Job seeker users can register and build their profile (online resume), and it is used for one click application.

When job seekers logged in and click "Apply Now" button to any job, I want Laravel to send an email attached with .PDF resume (generated from their online resume building page) to employer's inbox.

Note: I do not want to send their uploaded resume (.pdf/.doc) to employer's inbox because I want to promote my website's branding / resume template.

Please tell me how to achieve this. If any source code provided, I would appreciated.

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a html to pdf converter (something like http://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf). This will create the users profile in PDF format.

After the user clicked the button there will be an email sended to the employer with the attached pdf from the user.

It will look something like this:

```
    Mail::send('emails.reminder', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
        $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Your Reminder!');

        $m->attach($pathToFile);
    });
```

And with custom mail per email:

```
    Mail::send('emails.reminder', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
        $m->from('hello@app.com', 'Your Application');
        $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Your Reminder!');

        $m->attach($pathToFile);
    });
```

This will create the PDF, save it to the storage directory. You can use the views for the design:

```
public function createCollageCron($load_id) {
    $load = Loads::findOrFail($load_id);

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.collage', compact('load'));
    if ($pdf->save(storage_path('app/loadings/'.$load->id.'/collage.pdf'))) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope this works!

Comment: How about .env file? What should I ignore or do something with it?

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

Comment: If that's custom data you can make it available in the setup. When the user finished the setup you can write all the values to the .env file. (be sure to surround the values with "") @Naren

Comment: Excuse me. What do you mean please?

Comment: You want a setup for your laravel application right? So when you try to setup your application you need to check if its done correctly. Therefor you need to verify the email settings. After that's completed you can write the config to the .env file

Comment: I've done with the sending gmail now. Anyway, when I send it, everything is correct, except sender's email address. I used my sender's email as "someemail@gmail.com" but when the email is received, the sender's address becomes "username@premiumXX.web-hosting.com". I use namecheap web hosting.

Comment: What did you fill in at: `/config/app.php`, there you need to set the sender address by default. For custom I edited my code!

Comment: I have not filled anything about email yet. Please let me know what to fill and how?